# How can i sort this dict per datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

How can i sort this dict per datetime?
Is it possible?

```
{
1: {'l':{'created_on': datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 29, 17, 39, 26)}},
2: {'l':{'created_on': datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 23, 17, 39, 26)}},
3: {'l':{'created_on': datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 30, 17, 39, 26)}}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the [sorted()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) function on the values, with the datetime as the comparison key:

```
sorted(d.values(), key=lambda item: item["l"]["created_on"])
```

Comment: If you want to keep all information: sorted(d.items(), key = lambda k, it: it["l"]["created_on"])

Comment: And you can just wrap @rocksportrocker method there in an `OrderedDict()` if you want it back as a mapping.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a sorted list of keys for your dictionary `d` (dictionaries cannot be sorted by themselves):

```
>>> sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k: d[k]['l']['created_on'])
[2, 1, 3]
```

PS: If you really need a dictionary with sorted keys, the now standard [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) type is your friend (as described in the comments by rocksportrocker and agf after Frédéric's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can not sort a dict() itself. The dict has no implict order:

```
>>> print dict(a=3, b=2, c=1)
{'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

If you want to keep the full structure of your dict, you have to flatten your dict `dd` into a list `li` first. Then you can sort with the `datetime` value as a key:

```
import operator 

dd = { 1: ..... }

li = [] 

for (i, it) in dd.items():
    for (l, it1) in it.items():
        for (c, dt) in it.items():
            li.append((i, l, c, dt))
li.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(3))

print li
```

Comment: I don't see how this version keeps the full structure, or how the `sorted(d.items()...` fails to? Especially as it can be wrapped in an `OrderedDict` to get a mapping back, while this can't.

Comment: it keeps the keys from the first level, which is lost if you iterate over the values()

Comment: Ok, but not if you use `items()` which doesn't flatten, but retains the depth of the `dict` -- so saying you have to flatten it is wrong. You should really add that comment to this answer, since it's the best way to do this.